# My single page website doesn't have API calls and url paramaters. Can I Implement Angular Universal with firebase hosting without using cloud function

Tags: firebase, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an angular 9 application deployed in firebase. I am planning to implement Angular Universal SSR for SEO.

Could anyone please clarify my doubts regarding Angular 9 Universal + Firebase hosting.
(I am currently using Spark plan which does not includes cloud functions.)

1. Can I implement SSR without Firebase cloud functions ?

Also,

2. My website doesn't have API calls(other than Google Analythics on index.html), no database connectivity and no query string parameters. That means, my home page contents are always same**. In this case, can I use static server side rendering without cloud functions.
3. If this is possible, How to deploy the output to firebase ?

3.1, Will copy the dist folder contents to server works?

3.2 How to run SSR and non SSR version in my local?

Note: **My website is not static html page, I am providing some client side fuctionality using javascript/typescript code which does not have server calls.

Other than implementing Angular Universal, Is there any way to to achivbe SEO with Angular Apps?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via Angular pre rendering.

Prerendering does not requires cloud function or node support in server.
It is easy and Angular CLI version > 11 directly supports it.

Now Web crawlers can able to read the entire HTML content. Because the output of prerender is a rendered HTML file.

Steps

1. Install Angular Express Engine using the below command

   ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject project-example
2. Run the below command

   npm run prerender
3. Goto dist folder
4. Copy/deploy contents from the folder 'Browser' to server environment

Note that any code related to window, document, navigator will throw error and should be wrapped inside if condition like this.

```
if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
// your code accessing window, document, navigator.
}
```